# Intent not working in kotlin, Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am creating a splash screen for this I have used a Handler and starting and Intent to go to next Activity after Splash Screen but it's showing a error in my Intent. The error is **Unresolved reference: java**.Please help me...I am providing my whole code.

codes:

SplashActivity.kt

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spalsh)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
        }
        else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            )
        }
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
             val start:Intent = Intent(this,IntroActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(start)
                finish()
            },250)
    }
}
```

IntroActivity.kt

```
package com.aanda.tomatodiseaseprediction

import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Html
import android.text.Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class IntroActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var txtView:TextView? = null
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_time_screen)
        val first:String = getColoredSpanned("Dr","#000000")
        val second:String = getColoredSpanned("Plant","#2F9A1E")
        txtView = findViewById(R.id.drplant)
        txtView?.text = Html.fromHtml(first+""+second,FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
    }
    private fun getColoredSpanned(text: String, color: String): String {
        return "<font color=$color>$text</font>"
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.aanda.tomatodiseaseprediction">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TomatoDiseasePrediction">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TomatoDiseasePrediction.NoActionBar"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".IntroActivity"
            android:exported="false">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle App Level

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aanda.tomatodiseaseprediction"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Gradle Top Level

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

    }
    dependencies {
        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[SplashActivity.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbiSl.png)

[IntroActivity.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPlyY.png)

[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ4jD.png)

I am expecting to go to next activity but it is showing an error with **Unresolved reference: java**

Comment: Can you provide also your manifest.xml and your IntroActivity.kt ? Seems like the project can't find the class, maybe it's missing from somewhere

Comment: Sure, I am adding it!

Comment: Also add your gradle files so we can tell what plugin and Kotlin version you are on.

Comment: Okk, I am adding it

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
```

from `onCreate`. Use `if/else` blocks for `fromHtml`. If I am correct, because of the annotation, devices below API 26 might not find the `onCreate` function

Comment: Agree, this could be the solution